# loading javascript & css inside of javascript causing errors

Tags: javascript

i am trying to load js and css from inside of a script.  from quite a few old posts, something like this seems to be the preferred method of doing it:

```
        // load up css and js
[ './css/jqx.base.css'
, './js/Modernizr/Modernizr.custom.81162.js'
, './js/src/libraryOne.js'
, './js/src/libraryTwo.js'
, './js/src/libraryThree.js'
, './js/src/libraryLast.js'
].forEach(function(value, key)  {
        console.log('loading: ' + value);
        if  ( value.match(/\.css$/) )   {
                var headID     = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                var cssNode     = document.createElement('link');
                cssNode.href    = value;
                cssNode.type    = 'text/css';
                cssNode.rel     = 'stylesheet';
                cssNode.media   = 'screen';
                headID.appendChild(cssNode);
        } else if  ( value.match(/\.js$/) )     {
                var script      = document.createElement('script');
                script.src      = value;
                script.type     = 'text/javascript';
                script.async    = false;
                var scripts     = document.getElementsByTagName('script'[0]);
                scripts.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scripts);
        } else {
                console.log('bad one: ' + value );
        }
});
```

this works quite well MOST of the time, but some of the time i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Canvas' of undefined

and this is on a line of code that looks like this:

```
 this.drawer = Object.create(marksObject.Drawer[this.params.renderer]);
```

the fact that this is only happening occasionally tells me it probably has something to do with a timing issue regarding the script loading.  i tried setting async to true, false, and defer to true, false as well with no success.

the page loads perfectly every time when i just load using the regular  tags.

so, my first question is this:  is there a better way to load scripts from inside of javascript?

next question:  i looked at Require.js instead, but it was complaining about the package and prototypes, also a few posts seem to indicate that Require.js is obsolete.  is there another javascript loader that might be better at dealing with this timing issue?

any suggestions?

Comment: Require.JS is IMHO the best option.

Comment: aren't you missing a `)` in `document.getElementsByTagName('script'[0];` before your array index?

Comment: thanks, this was a cut/paste and formatted for the post - but i fixed it anyways.

Comment: Require.js was the first thing i tried, but i would need to reformat some code from github.  i would rather not have to do that if possible.